# Turn off scrolling outside of the scroll bar on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a website, which consists of multiple graphs and tables. On my mobile site it is difficult to scroll down the page on a touch screen device, as the tables also scroll on touch (there is little room to the side).

Is there a way that I can disable scrolling on the tables, apart from on the actual scroll bar itself? scrolling down the page is more important than scrolling through the charts, so this should be priority. However, our customers will still need to scroll through the tables to read all of the information listed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not make the width of the content equal to the device width?

Comment: or reflow the tables into a different layout to make them display better for mobile users

Comment: In my humble opinion, the answer you are looking for would be counter-intuitive from a UX perspective. Disabling scrolling in a table is likely to frustrate users who want to do just that. Considering alternative ways to present the data on smaller devices would be my best advice (possibly make a question in UX instead)

Comment: Thank you for your opinions. I will make a new question in UX for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting max-height of your tables something lesser than viewport and set `overflow:hidden` for mobile specifically. You can determine mobile either by media query or some explicit checks with useragent provided by browser.

FYI: You can use the newer ways to set height of `div` using `vh` instead of normal `px` way. But, mind you this is not cross browser compatible.